# Changing the if statement into a while statement

Tags: c

I'm trying to change an if statement into a while statement.
For example
`int A=1; if(A==1){};`
is similar to `int A=1 while(A!=1)`.
My If statement has no codes, I just need it to do nothing in order to avoid the else-if statements.

My If statement is inside 1 While statement and 1 If statement.
So I want the program to do the same thing in the while statement rather than going in 1 While statement and 1 If statement with an If statement with no code.

Original codes something like this

```
while(C1)
{
    if(C2)
    {
        if( h->data[temp] < h->data[temp*2] && h->data[temp] < h->data[temp*2+1] )
        {
             break;
        }
        else if(C4)
        {
            DO();
        }

    }
}
```

I've changed it to

```
while( C1 && h->data[temp] > h->data[temp*2] && h->data[temp] > h->data[temp*2+1] )
{
    if(C2)
    {
        if(C4)
        {
            DO();
        }

    }
}
```

and the result is different. The original code gives the correct result but the changed code gives an incorrect result. I've only changed the location to if to while and also changed the direction of the < operator to the > operator.

The total code seems like I've spent less effort in it, making down votes. So I'm posting the code somewhat like a pseudo code.

Comment: Not again such obfuscation crap!

Comment: WTB some whitespace. The DecWriter is long-gone; seriously. Obviously the results can differ. The first only terminates the outer-while when `C1` is *false*. The second can terminate on additional condition besides that.

Comment: " For example int A=1; if(A==1){}; is similar to int A=1 while(A!=1)" - No it is not. While will block if the condition is true. `if` won't.

Comment: I think it is a genuine question - there is no obfuscation here - just look at his "condition". (@Olaf and @WhozCraig) if you think it is poorly written please try to edit it

Comment: No, @Olaf is correct.  It's rubbish, again.  To use such an expression is insane; it's surely going to go wrong and result in an SO post because it's un-debuggable.  Get rid of it and replace with several lines of temp bool vars that can be individually and easily checked with a debugger.  Sorry, OP, but that code is just unfit for purpose.

Comment: @Abhi - YOU rewrite it.  If you understand it, go for it.

Comment: @Abhi: Any deliberate modification making code less readable or missusing languages constructs like that **is** obfuscation. One goal of good programming is to create readable and maintainable code. (and it would not harm if it also runs fast enough ... - CS viewpoint). So, the question asks about a problem which cannot be reproduced if using the constructs meant to be used -- `if`, not `while`.

Comment: And: asking the same question again doe not make it better.

Comment: @Olaf So if my original codes seems to be readable and the result is correct. Having a if statement without any codes would be alright then? and it would have been better for you to reply the second way not saying what a crap. I'm just a learner.

Comment: Check the conditional branches, and if they line up with the original. However, It will be easy to miss all the cases.

Comment: Use `while (X) { doY(); break; }` to replace `if (X) { doY(); }`.  Not that that's a good idea, but it's the general template you would follow.

Comment: It is correct as you defined it to be: "So I want the program to do the same thing in the while statement". You did not state what you actually expected. **I did not** state it is correct. My statement is not bijective.

Comment: @Olaf I guess then your statement doesn't give any help.

Comment: If does. However, this is a two-sided (3 sided for Vorlons) sword: You also have to notice and accept it. Apparently, you are not. Otherwise you would have at least provided a [mcve].

Comment: @양수현 if that is what you are learning, you need to unlearn it.  The position of Olaf and I is supported by the fact that you posted on SO at all - even you could not understand your own code.  You must not write code that you cannot easily debug.  I believe that to be self-evident.

Comment: @MartinJames I was curious about the alternative of changing an if to a while. For instance, while(1){ if(i==1) break; } can change in to while(i!=1){} so I thought that the statement above could make that change also. The code could be a little harder to understand. However, the code is not messy. Instead of ==, my present if statement has a > so i also made the it a < so it could be opposite. However, the result was different so I wanted to know what's the difference that's the purpose my question, not listening to others teaching lessons to me. Coding has many answers in a learner's view.

Comment: @MartinJames There might be an optimum solution. But right now I'm trying to figure out the ways to represent the code above. As if a tree can be represent by an array or a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For example int A=1; if(A==1){}; is similar to int A=1 while(A!=1).

As already mentioned, your loop is breaking. The above statement is also incorrect.

```
int a = 1;
if(a == 1) {} //this is true, and will happen once
```

BUT

```
int a = 1;
while(a != 1) {} //false on entry, skip loop ( never entered )
```

You could also consider a switch / case if you can isolate the condition.
This might achieve your goal of removing the ifs, and make the code more readable.

e.g

```
int a = 1;
while(a)
{
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1: ++a; continue;
        case 2: do();
        default: break;    //end loop
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the original code, if (for example) `h->data[temp]>h->data[temp*2]` were false, `DO()` wouldn't be executed, but the loop would continue.  In the new version, the loop would stop.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, there is no reason to obfuscate the code with an extra while statement; the original is perfectly clear. There is also no need for the `else` in your original:

```
while(C1)
{
    if(C2)
    {
        if( h->data[temp] < h->data[temp*2] && h->data[temp] < h->data[temp*2+1] )
        {
             break;
        }
        if(C4)
        {
            DO();
        }

    }
}
```